# Is there any workaround for getimagesize?

Tags: php, jpeg, exif, iptc

For some unknown reasons PHP getimagesize truncates my IPTC caption strings from JPGs. So iptcparse can only spit out what it gets. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all getimagesize() doesn't truncate anything! I thought, i could be a problem with the charset of IPTC ...

Maybe this could help you

```
 <?php 
    $IPTC_Caption = ""; 
    $size = getimagesize( $image_path, $info ); 
    if (isset($info["APP13"])) { 
        if($iptc = iptcparse( $info["APP13"] ) ) { 
           $IPTC_Caption = str_replace( "\000", "", $iptc["2#120"][0] ); 
           if(isset($iptc["1#090"]) && $iptc["1#090"][0] == "\x1B%G") {
                $IPTC_Caption = utf8_decode($IPTC_Caption); 
           }
       } 
    } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used more or less your code, that truncates my caption. But it turned out indeed, that this is not a problem with getimagesize(). It is already the Adobe Lightroom export function that truncates IPTC OBJECT NAME while leaving the XMP TITLE intact.